# Web Api Controller not resolving action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using .NET Core 2.2 and I have the controller below

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CarsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/cars/search")]
    [ActionName("search")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> SearchForCar([FromBody] SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

I am new to pure web api controllers.

I am confused about why when I post json to

```
http://localhost:51285/api/cars/search
```

I get 405 method not allowed?

I would normally have a route of

```
[Route("api/[controller]/action")]
```

That does work (once I remove route from the method attributes), but this wasn't the default provided in the template

Could someone let me know what I am missing?

Am I breaking convention by changing to

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you not using the root slash in your action "/", the MVC middleware will search concatenating the route for controller and the action, should work like this

```
[Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")] // Check the root slash as first character
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> SearchForCar([FromBody]
SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
```

Or like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] [ApiController] public class
CarsController : ControllerBase
```

Or

In controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] [ApiController] public class
CarsController : ControllerBase
```

In action:

```
[Route("search")] // [action] Takes the method name
public <ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>
SearchForCar([FromBody] SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
```